# Last Name Search SQL performance improvement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Looking for inputs on the following query that utilises a table variable retrieving last name results with the matching CustomerNumberID's.

1.

```
INSERT INTO #MatchingIndividuals (CustomerNumberID)
    SELECT DISTINCT(c.CustomerNumberID)
    FROM CustomerNumber c
    WHERE c.CustomerTypeID = 1
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM CustomerIndividualNameSearch cn
                INNER JOIN CustomerIndividualName cin
                    ON cn.CustomerIndividualNameID = cin.CustomerIndividualNameID
                CROSS JOIN #NameCriteria cnc
            WHERE cin.CustomerNumberID = c.CustomerNumberID
                AND cn.LastName LIKE cnc.LastName ESCAPE @escape)
    ORDER BY c.CustomerNumberID
    OFFSET @SKIP ROWS FETCH NEXT @ROWS ROWS ONLY
```

2.
#NameCriteria is declared as

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, MiddleName
        FROM dbo.CustomerIndividualNameCriteriaExpansion(@LastName, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @ExactSearch, @LastNameThreshold, @escape)'

            SET @where = @where + '
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM #NameCriteria cnc
                INNER JOIN CustomerIndividualNameSearch cn
                    ON ' + @namewhere + '
                INNER JOIN CustomerIndividualName cin
                    ON cn.CustomerIndividualNameID = cin.CustomerIndividualNameID
            WHERE cin.CustomerNumberID = c.CustomerNumberID)'
```

3.CustomerIndividualNameCriteriaExpansion is an inline table valued function that expands first, middle and last name for wildcard name searches.

Query is taking 30 sec or more to return. Suggestions?

Comment: Let's just say that `CROSS JOIN #NameCriteria cnc
` looks suspiciously like the cause. Do you understand what the performance effect of a CROSS JOIN is?

Comment: Depending on the db manager, the cross join may be turned into an inner join by the planner.   So it is code smell but not necessarily a performance problem.  However, for performance, please state which RDBMS you are using and tag the question appropriately since performance tuning is often very RDBMS specific.

Comment: Added `sql-server` and `tsql` tags based on the code in the question

Comment: Get the execution plan and attach it. Without it, we'd only be guessing at your problem.

Comment: I have feeling that you are just doing too much for simple lookup. Consider to reduce count of nesting levels, joins, data involved. Also, if you ask a question, please provide all the information. For example, we just have to guess what is stored in CustomerIndividualNameSearch, CustomerIndividualName tables. Also, provided #NameCriteria definition does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

# tables tend to be rather slow - try using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx) instead.

```
WITH NameCriteria (LastName, FirstName, MiddleName) 
as
(
    SELECT LastName, FirstName, MiddleName
    FROM dbo.CustomerIndividualNameCriteriaExpansion(@LastName, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @ExactSearch, @LastNameThreshold, @escape)'
)

SELECT DISTINCT(c.CustomerNumberID)
FROM CustomerNumber c
WHERE c.CustomerTypeID = 1
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 
        FROM CustomerIndividualNameSearch cn
            INNER JOIN CustomerIndividualName cin
                ON cn.CustomerIndividualNameID = cin.CustomerIndividualNameID
            CROSS JOIN NameCriteria cnc
        WHERE cin.CustomerNumberID = c.CustomerNumberID
            AND cn.LastName LIKE cnc.LastName ESCAPE @escape)
ORDER BY c.CustomerNumberID
OFFSET @SKIP ROWS FETCH NEXT @ROWS ROWS ONLY
```

Next up I'd look at the `CROSS JOIN` statement - you want to compare every record you have to every name criteria, but this could result in massive numbers of records going in to your `LIKE` statement.

Microsoft SQL is better at optimising `LIKE` with indexes if the pattern starts with the text, so `'something%'` is quicker than `'%something'` - that's going to depend on what `CustomerIndividualNameCriteriaExpansion` returns.

Finally you have a nested `EXISTS` statement with joins to the outer tables - these can be rather messy in query plans - have a look and see whether you have some slow table scans in there.